Casting an object in Spring Boot with Classes in diferent modules
I have a problem when trying to cast in Spring Boot, I have the following method in which I did the casting:
@Override
  public void modificarExpediente(AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand modifyCommand) {

    **var command = (EditarDevengadoCommand) modifyCommand;**
     //More more code
 

This method is called within an entire flow, making debug, at this point the object 'modifyCommand' is of type 'ModificarCommand' which is a class that extends from the class 'AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand'.
Additionally, the class 'EditarDevengadoCommand' is a class that extends 'ModificarCommand' which in turn extends 'AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand'.

As indication the class 'ModificarCommand' and 'AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand' are classes that belong to an external module, that is to say to a library which is imported in the pom.xml.

The classes would be like these:


//MODULE B
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
public class ModificarCommand extends AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand {

    .....

}

//MODULE B
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AbstractExpedienteSecuenciaCommand {

  ....
}

//Class in Modulo A that extends of a class from a Module B

public class EditarDevengadoCommand extends ModificarCommand {

  ....
}


The error I get is as follows:    ** //ACTUAL ERROR**

java.lang.ClassCastException: class ...ModuleB...ModificarCommand cannot be cast to class ...ModuleA....EditarDevengadoCommand (...ModuleB...ModificarCommand and ...ModuleA....EditarDevengadoCommand are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Previously I had an error involving Spring DevTools, like this:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class <Class_Name> cannot be cast to class <Class_Name> (<Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader <Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

But I deactivated spring dev tools as follows and now I have the error above:

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: false


If I understand your question correctly you're trying to downcast the modifyCommand parameter which is of type ModificarCommand and not EditarDevengadoCommand. If this is the case the following article should possibly give some more insight: https://www.javatpoint.com/upcasting-and-downcasting-in-java
